# Default contact for a number

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean

Is there a way to set a default contact for a specific number, which happens to be bound to multiple contacts?

I.e. for some reason Alpha and Bravo share a telephone number. Currently if I try to send a message to Alpha, it "appears" as I'm sending it to Bravo (the number is the same). Can I make it "appear" as I'm sending it to Alpha, instead?

NOTE: in case someone didn't read carefully, this is the **opposite** of selecting a default number for a contact (it's selecting a default contact for a number).

I'm using cm7 and cm10.1.2 on two different phones, and they both display this quirk.

Comment: Have you tried the combinations: Default on one contact-not default on other and default on both?

Comment: @py_script yes, it's already default in the desired contact, and not default in the other :/

Comment: Is there a similar way to do this for an email address?  My son starting using email before he was old enough for a gmail account.  So my wife gave him wife-son@gmail.com.  Now gmail from my wife (wife@gmail.com) comes up as "Son's name" not "Wife's name", which is annoying.

Comment: @Gdalya Any chance filtering and applying tags (labels) would work for you?  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/how-can-i-filter-incoming-email-based-on-plus-addressing-in-gmail

Comment: @Lohoris The filtering comment was for the e-mail comment above it (by Gdalya).

Comment: @A.M. oh, I see, I'll just delete my comment then

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're after, this should do the trick:

1. Add a `P` (pause) at the end of the phone number for whichever contact(s) you do *not* want to be the default.  *I imagine a `W` would also work, but I can only vouch for a `P`.*
2. Ensure the "default" contact (if that's what you mean) has the normal number.

In your scenario, just change Bravo's number from, say, `1-800-555-1234` to `1-800-555-1234P`.

I just tested this approach and both numbers dial.  *The first thing I tried was adding an extra digit, but that did **not** work.*

Comment: While the idea is great, for some weird reason it worked on 4.1 but not on 2.3 :(

Comment: However it apparently was just a cache problem: clearing contacts data did the trick, thanks!

Comment: My way did not work on 2.3?  That's a strange pattern.  I'm running 2.2, so...2.2 yes, 2.3 no, 4.1 yes??  Maybe it depends on the UI.  Ah well.  I'm glad it's all working for you now.

Comment: It stopped working right now, after upgrading to cm 10.1.2 (Android 4.2.2). Now I think that the `P` was really irrelevant, and what mattered were external factors that "happened" to be correctly aligned.

Comment: It worked here.  Maybe your newer version of Android was specifically programmed to more intelligently find number matches (ignore trailing `P`s and `W`s), which would kill this method.  ...a *more powerful* tactic for you would be to add a trailing `W` *and* a digit (W instead of P so that you are not prompted to release the last digit).  There is no way Android should ever combine numbers differentiated that way, since the trailing W#(...) is how some people put in numbers with different extensions.  Some uses of the number might not like the trailing "extension", but it is worth a try.

Comment: I added W1 but then calling that number didn't work anymore...

Comment: Wow.  Google must really be attacking this in newer versions then (though I can't imagine why).  I just tried dialing with an appended "W1" and an appended "P1", and *the calls **did** go through*.  (How can you ever program in a number with an extension if they break it like that, by the way??)

Comment: Side note:  I confused `P` and `W` in my comment from earlier today.  P is for pause (for about a second) before releasing the next part, and W is for wait for me to opt to release the next part.  So if you can get it to work, you want `P`.  Again, though, they both work for me.

Comment: Stopped working again in cm10, with no apparent reason. Workarounds are no good anymore, but unfortunately I guess there's no real solution either :/